# 1-step shortcut to delete entire row in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm going through a CSV with a couple thousand rows and want to quickly delete rows.

I tried `Control + -` but that offers me this menu:

[image]

Might sound minor, but because I'll be deleting so many rows, I'd really like this shortcut to just skip the menu & immediately delete the entire row.

Is there another shortcut that deletes the entire row, or some other way to set the default for this shortcut to delete the entire row?

Comment: Highlight the whole row by clicking on the row number to the left and hit `Ctrl -`

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner. are you aware of a keyboard-only solution?

Comment: i guess you could highlight a whole row with shift - space - shift and then hit cntrl -. i think i'll do that.

Comment: You could hold the ctrl key down as you select rows and then delete several rows at a time. You can also click and drag with this method to select several rows at a time.

Comment: that too. thanks! your tips are making my job a lot easier.

Comment: Once you have deleted the first row, you can use "F4" to repeat your last action (in this case deleting a row).

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can save your time, by deleting in one go.**

**Step 1:** Click on column that is responsible to delete the row.

**Step 2**: Select Data > Filter-> Custom Filter.

**Step 3:** Select the column header arrow "Filter arrow".

**Step 4:** Select Text Filters or Number Filters or whatever you want.

**Step 5:** Click OK

Then you will get results

**Step 6:** Select all the results or all the rows

**Step 7:** Right-click and choose the option to delete.

And delete all the filtered rows

**And then clear the filter.**